# Would I gain a performance boost by normalizing this table?

Tags: php, mysql, join, database-normalization

I'm running a sort of forum modification code on my server. In my database, I have a **HUGE** table called `core`, which basically includes all the admin-editable settings, of which there are a lot. My question is, should I normalize this?

I've created a fiddle to show you how large this table is: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4536/1

You'll see some columns called `gear_notifications`, `gear_bank`, `gear_*` etc. These indicate whether a certain system is turned on. For example, if `gear_bank=1`, then the Bank System is turned on. At the moment, in the `__construct` of my DB file, I run the following query:

```
$settings = mysql_query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(d.domain) AS domains, GROUP_CONCAT(d.zb) AS zb_info, c.* FROM core c JOIN domains d ON d.cid = c.id WHERE c.id ='$cid' LIMIT 1");
```

Ignoring the `JOIN` you can straight away see a problem here; the query returns EVERY field from the `core` table, regardless of whether the corresponding system is turned on. For example, if `gear_bank=0`, the query will still return `bank_name`, `bank_history_perpage`, `bank_*` etc. While this doesn't present any physical problem with how the code runs (as it can just ignore any data it does not need), I'd much prefer if it didn't have to load that data.

Would I be better off creating one table called `core` which has all the `gear_*` values, then corresponding tables (`core_bank`, `core_*` etc) for their corresponding values?

I've been querying  this (bad pun, sorry!) for a while now and I just don't know enough to work out whether this will provide a performance boost for my code. Note that the above query will be run on EVERY page.

If I were to revert to the new system, i.e the multiple tables, how would I get all the information I need? I don't want to run one query to `core` to work out which systems are turned on, then subsequently run an extra query on all corresponding tables. I'd much prefer one query which `JOIN`s all necessary tables based on the values of `gear_*` in `core`. Would that be possible?

I've not yet released this forum modification so I can make as many changes as I like without any real-world impact `:)` .

Comment: You absolutely should normalize this. Here's a good place to start: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30646

Comment: You'll see some kind of performance gain if you normalize this, if only because the database is doing less work.

Comment: i also suggest normalizing - in either case you should optimize the sql to return just the rows you want.

Comment: Ok thank-you. Can you tell me whether what I said in the second-to-last paragraph is achievable?

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: Also switch to the Innodb engine. MyISAM won't enforce foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 0):

If you split your core into multiple tables you can then use NULL to indicate if a particular entry has info for a particular system.   The joins will then work as expected.

However, your table really is not that big and it's doubtful that you will actually notice any speed improvement at the application level by breaking it up.

And if you don't need to query on individual columns then just use one TEXT column, put all your attributes in an array and then serialize the array into the text column.

Comment: Could you give me an example query to run using the `JOIN` with `NULL`?

Comment: Just a plain left join will do the trick.  sql is smart enough to know that if your foreign key is NULL then there no need to link to the other table.